# Retrieving string from SQlite and converstion to sql date

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have used the following Code to save date into DB of Sqlite `( java.sql.Date)`

```
public String dateToDB ( Date date)
    {
       String convertedDate = date.toString(); // yyyy-mm-dd
       return convertedDate;
    }
```

How can i convert the recovered String into date?

```
private Date dateFromColumn(String columName, Cursor result)
    {
   // ???????
    return date   
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this in the Docs:

> Date.valueOf(String dateString) creates a Date from a string
>   representation of a date in SQL format: yyyy-MM-dd

This means four you:

```
private Date dateFromColumn(String columName, Cursor result)
{
  String strDate = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("yourcolumnname..."));
  return Date.valueOf(strDate);   
}
```